# Unable to use parse from my android device in Ionic App

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, ionic-framework

I am trying to run an ionic app. I have integrated this app to Parse. When i run this app on it works fine but when i run this app on my android device it is giving me error that parse is not defined. I have added android platform to it  and i have added application Id and JavaScript Key to my App.
I am getting this error :

```
E/Web Console(28568): Uncaught ReferenceError: Parse is not defined
```

I have add `parse.js` in my file with right path

Comment: Post your source code please.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to get services like Parse and Firebase to work with Ionic has historically been tough. The instructions on their websites are not comprehensive enough. My best suggestion is to change to a native Android app.